# Getting the length of a file in characters

Tags: c++, file

Here's my function for getting the length of a file, in characters:

```
unsigned int GetFileLength(std::string FileName)
{
std::ifstream InFile(FileName.c_str());
unsigned int FileLength = 0;
while (InFile.get() != EOF) FileLength++; 
InFile.close();
return FileLength;
}
```

How can this be improved?

Comment: of course you are assuming this is an ASCII file. 1 byte == 1 char. Lets hope there are no foreigners around with their pesky unicode junk :-). Also note the returning uint is a little optimistic in todays world, files get bigger than 4gb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just seek to the end of the file and grab the value:

```
ifstream is;
is.open (FileName.c_str(), ios::binary );
is.seekg (0, ios::end);
length = is.tellg();
```

Answer (score 6):

I dislike seeking, so here's my non-seeking approach.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

off_t GetFileLength(std::string const& filename)
{
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(filename.c_str(), &st) == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
    return st.st_size;
}
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity, though something in the back of my head says that stat is not portable.

Comment: Well, `stat` is defined in POSIX. If that's not portable, I don't know what is. :-P

Comment: @Chris--you're absolutely right! It's not ANSI C, but it's definitely POSIX. And I believe even Windows supports stat.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is accuracy important? I believe you could try to get the filesize and divide this by the amount of bytes the formatting uses. This could give a good estimate of the amount of characters in the file.

I say estimate because I might be forgetting about possible headers and such, although I believe a simple text file doesn't have that.

Comment: It does need to be accurate.

Comment: Well, considering you can get the exact file size (so not size on disk), as e.g. in the answer of Mark, it should be accurate. Mark's answer assumes single byte encoding. If this is the case, consider it your answer.

Comment: The file is opened in binary mode.  Encoding doesn't matter.

Comment: @Mark Loeser: He wants to get the amount of 'characters' in the file as far as I understand, not the amount of bytes (although that might be the same, yes)

Comment: You are right, my mistake. It was pretty early when I looked at this, so yea...I missed the "characters" part :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `std::ios::ate`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

size_t getFileSize( std::string fileName ) {
    std::ifstream file( fileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate );
    size_t fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.close();

    return fileSize;
}
```

`std::ios::ate` opens the file with the pointer(s) at the end. `file.eof()` would return `true`.